# Construction of an open set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\lim_{r \to 0^+} \frac{|E \cap B_r(0)|}{|B_r(0)|}$ DNE

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

My task is the following:

> Construct an open set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$\lim_{r \to 0^+} \frac{|E \cap B_r(0)|}{|B_r(0)|}$$ does not exist

Here, $| \cdot |$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $B_r(0)$ is a ball of radius $r$ centered at the origin. I'm a bit unsure of how to go about this particular problem. We previously used the Lebesgue points Theorem to show that for any Lebesgue measurable set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $$1 = \lim_{r \to 0^+} \frac{|E \cap B_r(x)|}{|B_r(x)|}$$ held for a.e. $x \in E$. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A non-empty open set does not have measure $0$.

Comment: Oh right okay! My bad - I'll post an edit!

Comment: Try playing around with a sequence of non-overlapping open intervals of positive real numbers monotonically approaching $0.$ For example, use $(0.001, \, 1),$ then use a very very tiny open interval in the middle of $(0.0001,\,0.001)$ (so small that it's length is tiny compared to $0.0001),$ then fill "almost all of" the interval $(0, \,0.0001)$ for a third open interval, then use a very very tiny interval in the middle of $(0,L),$ where $L$ is the left endpoint of the third interval, $\ldots$ In the case of ${\mathbb R}^n$ use the open sets between appropriate-radii concentric balls.

Comment: *In the case of* ${\mathbb R}^n$ *use the open sets between appropriate-radii concentric balls.* --- Or use appropriate sized balls approaching the origin, but it'll be easier to get the extreme case of $\liminf = 0$ and $\limsup = 1$ using regions between appropriate pairs of concentric balls centered at the origin.